# Erro ao carregar dropdownlist em cascata

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdown

Estou tentando carregar um dropdownlist cidades  conforme o estado selecionado e estou me deparando com um erro. Eu consegui realizar a operação em um template que baixei da internet, mas não estou conseguindo em meu projeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código está abaixo:
 O código JS para fazer a chamada.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ID_ESTADO").change(function () {
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            var ddlCidades = $("#ID_CIDADE");
            var statesProgress = $("#states-loading-progress");
            statesProgress.show();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("getCidades"))",
                data: { "ID_ESTADO": selectedItem },
                success: function (data) {
                    ddlCidades.html('');
                    $.each(data, function (ID_CIDADE, option) {
                        ddlCidades.append($('<option></option>').val(option.ID_CIDADE).html(option.NOME));
                    });
                    statesProgress.hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.');
                    statesProgress.hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Os dropdownList:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ESTADO.NOME, "ESTADO")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID_ESTADO, new SelectList(Model.lstEstados, "ID_ESTADO", "NOME").OrderBy(p => p.Text), "", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "ID_ESTADO", @name = "ID_ESTADO", @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_ESTADO, "", htmlAttributes: new { @style = "color: red;" })
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CIDADE.NOME, "CIDADE")
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID_CIDADE, new SelectList(Model.lstCidades, "ID_CIDADE", "NOME").OrderBy(p => p.Text), htmlAttributes: new { @id = "ID_CIDADE", @name = "ID_CIDADE", @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_CIDADE, "", htmlAttributes: new { @style = "color: red;" })
    <span id="states-loading-progress" style="display: none;">Por favor aguarde..</span>
</div>
```

**E a Action que está sendo executada:**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult getCidades(string ID_ESTADO)
    {
        int id = 0;
        bool isValid = Int32.TryParse(ID_ESTADO, out id);
        var result = db.CIDADEs.Where(p => p.ID_ESTADO == id).ToList();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

O código JS esta sendo executado, a Action está sendo chamada e a lista carregada normalmente. O problema está no momento de carregar o dropdown CIDADE.

Comment: o link para acesso ao código de exemplo: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/730953/Cascading-Dropdown-List-With-MVC-LINQ-to-SQL-and-A

Comment: no append, tente desta maneira    ddlCidades.append($('<option />').attr('value', option.ID_CIDADE).text(option.NOME));

Comment: Já colocou um *breakpoint* naquele *callback* `error` pra ver qual o erro?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu tentei debugar o código JSon e não debugou. De qualquer forma consegui resolver. troquei a linha de código abaixo:
ddlCidades.append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));

Valeu pelo apoio